# How to display in the Nightwatch.js Report.Html all the outputs and my log that appears in the console

Tags: logging, report, reporting, nightwatch.js

In some nightwatch.js tests I use console.log to print some variables values or comments. I would like to know if there is a way to print the console.log of the console in a nightwatch.js report since only nightwatch commands/assertions are visible. What I want to do is to display a report that contains all results like when I run the test in the console. Thank you in advance

Comment: Example: When nightwatch report.html is generated my comments are not present in the console.log.

Report.Html 
 v Login - Element #loginButton was visible after 75 ms
 v Expected element <body> text to not contain: "Login o password errate" - condition was met in 823ms
 
 
 Console Nightwatch
 v Login - Element #loginButton was visible after 75 ms
 v Login - Element #loginButton was visible after 75 ms
 v Expected element <body> text to not contain: "Login o password errate" - condition was met in 823ms

LA LOGIN EFFETTUATA CORRETTAMENTE

Answer (score 0):

why not use [assertions](https://nightwatchjs.org/api/commands/#assertions) instead?

```
browser.assert.ok(true, "Your custom message");
```

where ***browser**: NightwatchBrowser*